# Отображение php секций в html

Tags: php, .htaccess, apache

Здравствуйте. Есть пару очень старых блогов, которые необходимо перенести на новый хост. Сайты представляют собой кашу из html и php в .htm файлах.
На старом хостинге все работало путем добавления в .htaccess следующей строки:

> AddType application/x-httpd-php .html .htm

На новом хостинге данная фишка не работает(php вставки отображаются текстом в htm файлах, сами .php файлы отрабатывают нормально)

Если делать так:

> AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php .htm .html

тоже самое с htm файлами, только уже php файлы не выполняются а загружаются.

Так же как и на старом хостинге стоит Apache. Какие действия еще можно предпринять что бы php вставки отображались в htm файлах?

Comment: Там точно php модуль апача установлен? чисто php файл выполняется или так же код отображается?

Comment: Да, php отрабатывает нормально.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

После общения с саппортом оказалось, что необходимо было добавить этот хендлер для LsPHP:

> AddHandler application/x-httpd-lsphp .html .htm

Answer (score 0):

Вот так можно

```
echo ' AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .html ' | sudo  tee -a /etc/apache2/ httpd.conf
```

А также можно сделать конфигурацию в php.ini файле в директиве short_open_tag поставить

short_open_tag = On

По пути апача есть такой конфигурационный файл

/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/dir.conf

поменять свот этого

```
<IfModule mod_dir.c>
DirectoryIndex index.html index.cgi index.pl index.php index.xhtml 
index.htm
</IfModule>
```

на вот это

```
<IfModule mod_dir.c>
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.cgi index.pl index.xhtml 
index.htm
</IfModule>
```

Comment: РАЗУМЕЕТСЯ, пояснить, при чем здесь DirectoryIndex, наш недалекий друг не в состоянии

Comment: Может у него сайт решен с помощью технологий индекс страници что бы URL был без конечного файла.  например: http://my.site/robota.php вместо этого делается следующее http://my.site/index.php тогда в браузере покажется http://my.site/ 

https://myrusakov.ru/php-directoryindex.html

Comment: Кто бы сомневался, что вся эта чудовищная каша у тебя в голове - это результат курсов идиота русакова.

Comment: Результат курсов но увы Другого Идиота, плюс Книга какая? -Кевин Янк - PHP и MySQL. От новичка к профессионалу - 2013